# Ansible will not use `ssh_type` variable at the individual action level

Tags: ansible

I'm having a problem transferring a file via scp to a cisco device in Ansible. That's discussed in another SO thread. I found I can solve the problem by setting the `ansible_network_cli_ssh_type` variable to `paramiko`. The default behavior is for the ssh_type to be `libssh` and if I use `paramiko` the problem is solved.

However, even though it worked for a while for some reason Ansible stopped honoring the variable I was setting and continues to use `libssh`, as seen in the debug output:

```
<172.22.143.50> invoked shell using ssh_type: libssh
```

I commented out my entire playbook and moved the one task to the top and started troubleshooting. I found that, if I include the `cisco.ios.ios_facts` action prior to the `ansible.netcommon.net_put` action, Ansible no longer honors the variable telling it to use `paramiko` and instead it uses `libssh`.

Here's the sample code:

```
---
# Ansible Playbook to upgrade switch firmware.

# Cisco IOS handler
- name: UPGRADE SWITCHES
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: CHECK CURRENT VERSION
      cisco.ios.ios_facts:

    - name: COPY IMAGE TO DEVICE
      ansible.netcommon.net_put:
        src: "files/{{ firmware }}"
        dest: "flash:/{{ firmware }}"
      vars:
        ansible_command_timeout: 1200
        ansible_network_cli_ssh_type: paramiko # Bypass libssh bug by using paramiko
```

If I comment out the `ios_facts` action, it works.

```
  tasks:
    # - name: CHECK CURRENT VERSION
    #  cisco.ios.ios_facts:
```

Debug output:

```
<172.22.143.50> ssh type is set to paramiko
```

I think it might have something to do with it reusing the existing socket that was created in the previous step.

At `ios_facts` step:

```
<172.22.143.50> local domain socket does not exist, starting it
<172.22.143.50> control socket path is /home/vscode/.ansible/pc/305bf6e7c3
```

At `net_put` step:

```
<172.22.143.50> found existing local domain socket, using it!
<172.22.143.50> local domain socket path is /home/vscode/.ansible/pc/305bf6e7c3
```

When it worked previously, there might've been a long delay in the action immediately before the `net_put` action that caused a new socket to be created (that's speculation). If I add the variable globally in the inventory file, then it works again. But, of course, all tasks are then using paramiko.

Why is Ansible ignoring my variable now? Especially when I think it worked for a while prior to that before I added more to my playbook. What behavior am I not understanding here? Is it not possible to switch ssh_types at a task level under certain conditions?